# User Exists (0.2ms) SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

In my application when i tried to create a user with

```
 User.create(email:"jnan@gmail.com",encrypted_password: "foobar",name:"jnan")
```

It shows

```
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'jnan@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
 (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<User id: nil, email: "jnan@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "foobar", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "jnan">
```

my user contains

```
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, name: string)
```

Comment: Check your validation errors.

Comment: BTW you should probably set `password` and `password_confirmation` instead of `encrypted_password`.

Comment: or take devise or any other auth gemt. lol

Comment: Are you using devise? To check the validation errors, do something like `user = User.create(...`, then type `user.errors.messages`

Comment: Ya...the problem was solved, thanks for info,by the way i accepted @MarekLipka answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting `encrypted_password`, you should set `password` and `password_confirmation`:

```
password = 'foobar'
User.create(email:'jnan@gmail.com',password: password, password_confirmation: password, name: 'jnan')
```

Comment: yep, if OP is using devise, and from the table/columns it seems they do, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Ha, a bit weird that the discussion leading to this answer is on another answer *confused* :) And then the OP's problem is solved and they forget to accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

Marek is right, You should set password and password_confirmation while creating any record. You should not use encrypted_password.

When you pass password and password_confirmation to devise it check both for equality using attribute accessor and If validation goes well, Devise internally create a md5 sting for password that saved in encrypted_password feild. So no one can see password directly.

```
2.1.0 :002 > User.create(email:"jnan@gmail.com",encrypted_password: "foobar")
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (124.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jnan@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<User id: nil, email: "jnan@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "foobar", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, profile_image: nil, gender: nil, date_of_birth: nil> 
2.1.0 :003 > User.create(email:'jnan@gmail.com',password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password')
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jnan@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (24.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = '1442820d0b7521559ec07584408c6fdb6490444117383d76f6bf1dfc6dd90af6' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  SQL (246.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "created_at", "email", "encrypted_password", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["confirmation_sent_at", Tue, 08 Sep 2015 08:24:55 UTC +00:00], ["confirmation_token", "1442820d0b7521559ec07584408c6fdb6490444117383d76f6bf1dfc6dd90af6"], ["created_at", Tue, 08 Sep 2015 08:24:54 UTC +00:00], ["email", "jnan@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$Uw9088ovsHC/tCeEN0aJGeI83ax7bjXD2RcQHjvlLg.SovJcyz1MS"], ["updated_at", Tue, 08 Sep 2015 08:24:54 UTC +00:00]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to puts unique email to database.

The old one `jhan@gmail.com` is taken

Comment: even i tried with random mail it gives same message

Comment: Show us your `User` model

Comment: the application uses devise gem. and there are no validations

Comment: @vjnan369 There are validations since it's devise model. Show your validation errors.

Comment: It shows  `@messages={:password=>["can't be blank"]} cant be blank`,but i have encrypted_password as password attribute.@MarekLipka

Comment: I thought so. Like I wrote, set `password` and `password_confirmation` instead of `encrypted_password`.

Comment: thanks,it worked for me.write answer for this i will accept it. @MarekLipka

Answer (score 0):

This also works (without `password_confirmation`)

```
user = User.create(name: "raj",email:"raj@gmail.com",password: "foobar")
```